# How to Enable Right-Click and desktop icons in Elementory OS Juno

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno, dconf

I am not able to use Right Click Option to Run Terminal at a precise location in the Latest Elementory OS Juno.I humbly request your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the right-click menu, mouse to "Open in", and select Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is an outstanding bug that means a right-click does not always focus the item you are clicking on (see https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/602).  As a temporary workaround, make sure the item has a blue background (i.e. it is focused and selected) before right-clicking.  You can do this by using the primary (left) button to select on the helper or (in ColumnView where you are clicking on other than the current column) the keyboard to focus and select.

There is a fix for this already submitted for approval and merging.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to "Desktop Icons", elementaryos does not support putting shortcuts or other icons onto the desktop I am afraid.